# Why can object property keys be omitted in javascript / typescript if they match the variable name?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example, in typescript:

```
interface X = {
    name: string;
}

const name = "Joe";

const y: X = {
    name
}

// equivalent to

const z: X = {
    name: name
}
```

AFAIK this only works because the variable name is "matched" to the expected property names of the interface. How is typescript/js accomplishing this under the hood?

Comment: It's in the language spec; it's the way it works. (It hasn't always worked that way however.)

Comment: Do you have a pointer (no pun intended) to documentation on this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer *edit* specifically, in 12.2.6.9